# MarkLogic REST API for Forest restore

Tags: marklogic

Is there a MarkLogic REST API for forest-restore?

```
xdmp:forest-restore(xdmp:forest("My-Forest"),"/backups/Data/Forests/Documents")
```

Comment: You only want to restore a single forest, not a database restore? https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]#RestoreDB

Comment: Because the source database is 11.0.0 and the destination database is 10.xx so I can't restore the entire database.